# Efficient way to calculate the "product" of a discrete convolution

Tags: arrays, matlab, multiplication, convolution, sliding-window

I'm looking for an elegant way to compute the "product" of a discrete convolution, instead of the sum.

Here is the formula of a **discrete convolution**:

[image]

In this case we can use: `conv(x,y)`

Now I would like to implement those operations

[image]

Of course I can use a loop, but I'm looking for a trick in order to linearize this operation.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
f = [2 4 3 9 7 1]
g = [3 2 1]

dist = length(g)-1;

for ii = 1:length(f)-dist
    x(ii) = prod(f(ii:ii+dist).*g)
end
```

> x =
>
> ```
> 144    648   1134    378
> ```

Comment: If your inputs (`f`,`g`) always contain integers, you might be able to gain some speed, regardless of algorithm, by casting them to `uint16` or etc. (assuming you can rule-out overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution partly inspired by [Dev-iL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39330812/6579744) to relatively the same question

```
exp(sum(log(g))+conv(log(f),[1 1 1],'valid'))
```

or

```
exp(sum(log(g))+movsum(log(f),numel(g),'Endpoints', 'discard'))
```

since `exp(sum(log(x))) = prod(x)`

But here instead of one vector we have two vectors `f` and `g`.

The desired formula can be reformulated as:

[image]

Timing in octave:

```
f= rand(1,1000000);
g= rand(1,100);

disp('----------EXP(LOG)------')
tic
    exp(sum(log(g))+conv(log(f),ones(1,numel(g))));
toc

disp('----------BSXFUN------')
tic
    ind = bsxfun(@plus, 0:numel(f)-numel(g), (1:numel(g)).');
    x = prod(bsxfun(@times, f(ind), g(:)),1);
toc
disp('----------HANKEL------')
tic
    prod(g)*prod(hankel(f(1:numel(g)), f(numel(g):end)));
toc

disp('----------CUMPROD-----')
tic
    pf = cumprod(f);
    x = prod(g)*pf(numel(g):end)./[1 pf(1:(end-numel(g)))];
toc
```

Result:

```
----------EXP(LOG)------%rahnema1
Elapsed time is 0.211445 seconds.
----------BSXFUN--------%Luis Mendo
Elapsed time is 1.94182 seconds.
----------HANKEL--------%gnovice
Elapsed time is 1.46593 seconds.
----------CUMPROD-------%gnovice
Elapsed time is 0.00748992 seconds.
```

Comment: To match the results from the sample in the question, you would want to add `..., 'valid')` to the `conv` call and `..., 'Endpoints', 'discard');` to the `movsum` call.

Answer (score 5):

### `cumprod` solution: (very efficient)

```
>> pf = cumprod(f);
>> x = prod(g).*pf(numel(g):end)./[1 pf(1:(end-numel(g)))]

x =

         144         648        1134         378
```

This first takes the cumulative product of `f` using [`cumprod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html). By dividing each element by the cumulative product 3 elements before it, we get the product of each `numel(g)`-wide sliding window along `f`. Then just multiply by the product of the elements of `g`.

**NOTE:** When `f` has many elements, or extreme values (large or small), you could run into issues with accuracy or underflow/overflow when performing the cumulative product. One potential way to mitigate this would be to apply a scaling to `f` before the cumulative product, then undo it afterward:

```
c = ...set a scaling factor...
pf = cumprod(f./c);
x = prod(c.*g).*pf(numel(g):end)./[1 pf(1:(end-numel(g)))];
```

The choice for `c` could be something like `mean(abs(f))` or `max(abs(f))` so that the scaled `f` gives results that are better bounded (i.e. values closer to 1). This doesn't appreciably change the timing results below.

---

### `hankel` solution: (not as efficient but still interesting)

```
>> x = prod(g).*prod(hankel(f(1:numel(g)), f(numel(g):end)))

x =

         144         648        1134         378
```

The call to [`hankel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) creates a matrix where each column has the contents of one of the `numel(g)`-wide sliding windows in it. Taking the product down each column then multiplying by the product of the elements of `g` gives your answer. However, for large vectors `f` and/or `g` this could involve a lot of extra computation and use a lot of memory.

---

### Timing the results:

I tested 6 solutions (the loop in your question, 2 solutions from [rahnema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367342/52738) (`conv(log)` and `movsum(log)`), the `bsxfun` solution from [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366988/52738), and my `cumprod` and `hankel` solutions) using `f = rand(1,1000000);` and `g = rand(1,100);` and averaging over 40 iterations. Here's what I got (running Windows 7 x64, 16 GB RAM, MATLAB R2016b):

```
solution    | avg. time (s)
------------+---------------
loop        |       1.10671
conv(log)   |       0.04984
movsum(log) |       0.03736
bsxfun      |       1.20472
cumprod     |       0.01469
hankel      |       1.17704
```

Comment: I think if `f` contains values such as `4 5 10` instead of `rand` result of `cumprod(f)` will not be so reliable

Comment: @rahnema1: You're right. I addressed how that could be compensated for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The cumprod method is indeed really efficient, but if f contains a 0 this method will failed, and it's IMO a little bit dangerous to implement such a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that avoids loops:

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 0:numel(f)-numel(g), (1:numel(g)).');
x = prod(bsxfun(@times, f(ind), g(:)), 1);
```

This works as follows. `ind` represents the sliding window of indices, each colummn corresponding to a displacement. For example, if `g` has size `3` the matrix `ind` will be

```
1 2 3 4 ...
2 3 4 5 ...
3 4 5 6 ...
```

This is used to index into `f`. The result is multiplied (with broadcast) by `g` as a column. Finally the product of elements of each column is computed.